# React Router V4 can not get the match params

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm following the React for Beginner tutorial by using the React Router V4.However I can't get my params in my component.Here's part of my code.

```
const Root = () => {
return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={StorePicker} />
          <Route Path='store/:storeId' component={App} />
          <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
)
}
```

StorePicker component:

```
class StorePicker extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <form className="store-selector" onSubmit={(e) => this.goToStore(e)}>
                <h2>Please Enter A Store</h2>
                <input type="text" ref={(input) => { this.storeInput= input; }} defaultValue={getFunName()} placeholder="Store Name" required/>
                <button type="submit">Visit Store</button>
            </form>
        )
    }

    goToStore(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        const storeInput = this.storeInput.value
        console.log(storeInput)
        this.props.history.push(`store/${storeInput}`)
    }

}
```

And in my App component I can't get the storeId.

```
//storeId is undefine
this.props.match.params.storeId
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you provide whole StorePicker component file?

Comment: @AnkitParikh I have updated my code now

Comment: Does it need to be `<Route path='/store/:storeId' component={App} />`?

Comment: @bennygenel No, it is just a practice project

Comment: I guess I was not clear. I'm trying to say, It might be related to that you are missing a slash on your path. `path='store/:storeId'` might need to be `path='/store/:storeId'`

Comment: @bennygenel whether the slash exists, there's no difference

Comment: Can you add code from `App` component please

Comment: @bennygenel the App component is bit long.I paste the code on the js bin.http://jsbin.com/vunelog/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2):

React Router 4 has been re-vamped:

the router context is no longer injected into the props automatically (if i remember correctly this is how react router 3 worked, or depending on how you specified the context of the component that the router rendered).

try this:

`import { withRouter } from 'react-router';`

when exporting your component, wrap it:

`withRouter(MyComponent)`

this should correctly inject the props you are looking for so they arent undefined.

I took this directly from the react router site:

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

Comment: So I should export my App component like  export default withRouter(App)?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure but `withRouter` is for Components which is not directly related to Routes. Rather than passing props to each child you can use `withRouter`

Comment: Yea so declare your class at the top like: `class App extends React.Component`. then at the bottom `export default withRouter(App)`, granted i dont know your app setup, but i am assuming this is your problem of why its undefined

Comment: just reviewed your code, and assuming it works, you would want to import withRouter in your `StorePicker` component, saw you mentioned `App`.

Comment: I still can not get the router param.